# Software to add watermark to photos in bulk?

Tags: software-recommendation

Can anyone recommend any software that adds a watermark to photos in bulk?

I've been searching for a while now and I haven't found any quality ones.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Phatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatch). It seems like it's pretty much abandonware these days, the latest release was in 2010, but I've been using it for probably that long and it makes batch editing very easy. It's in the Ubuntu repositories, so you can install it pretty easily from the Software Centre or from Synaptic (or with `sudo apt-get install phatch`). Unfortunately, the website seems to be down at the moment, so the documentation is also down - but I'm sure you can figure it out by pressing buttons.   **;-)**

To add your own watermark to the Phatch option, save it as a PNG into `~/.local/share/phatch/watermarks`. If you already have Phatch open when you copy the watermark image across, you will need to close it and open it again.

Then add the "Watermark" action in Phatch, and select your image file. Then add a "Save" action, and run the action list against your files.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own very quickly with image magick and bash/python

Look at this [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#anno_below) . (if you want more realistic watermarking image magick can still help you)

Use the commands in the above tutorial after running

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then put all the images you want watermarked in 1 directory and open a terminal in that directory.

Then run

```
<im command> ./*
```